# XML-RPC returns wrong double precision

Tags: postgresql, odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-8

I have written my own Odoo module where I added a property `weight` to the `product.template` model.

The implementation in the Python code is

```
weight = fields.Float('Weight', digits=(12,4))
```

I also changed the view so that I can set this value in the form. So I created a new product in the Odoo GUI and set the `weight` to `7.85`. After storing the value, `7.8500` is shown which seems to be reasonable as the definition declares 4 float digits. The value stored in the PostgreSQL is a `numeric` and the value is `7.8500`. So this all seems to be correct.

When I now want to get the product with the Odoo API which is based on XML-RPC I do not get `7.8500` but `7.8500000000000005`

```
<member>
    <name>weight</name>
    <value><double>7.8500000000000005</double></value>
</member>
```

So my question is, why is this and how can I prevent this?

**EDIT:**
This behavior occurs whenever I have 2 decimal places. So when I take `7.8` instead of `7.85` the return value is `7.8`.